# how to compare the decimal value with integer in iPhone?

Tags: ios, validation

Hi i have a minimum value as 100 and maximum value as 400. User should enter within this values. If they enter 400.5 it shouldn't accept. that is the validation for my textfield. I used the following code

```
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
                [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
                NSNumber *textFieldNumber = [formatter numberFromString:[dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld text]];
                NSNumber *MaxNumber = [formatter numberFromString:[[healthyHeartFieldsAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag] objectForKey:@"MaxVal"]];
                NSNumber *MinNumber = [formatter numberFromString:[[healthyHeartFieldsAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag] objectForKey:@"MinVal"]];


                if ([self checkForDecimalValue:dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.text]) 
                {





                    if (([textFieldNumber decimalValue] < [MinNumber decimalValue]) || ([textFieldNumber decimalValue] > [MaxNumber decimalValue]) ) {

                        if ([textFieldNumber decimalValue] < [MinNumber decimalValue]) {

                            Custom_Alert *alert=[[Custom_Alert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Value you entered in %@ is outside the acceptable range.Please correct and Continue ",[[healthyHeartFieldsAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag] objectForKey:@"TestName"]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                            [alert show];
                            enterAlert=YES;
                            [alert release];

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Custom_Alert *alert=[[Custom_Alert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Value you entered is %@ outside the acceptable range.Please correct and Continue",[[healthyHeartFieldsAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag] objectForKey:@"TestName"]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                            [alert show];
                            enterAlert=YES;
                            [alert release];

                        }

                    }


                }
```

If i use this code. it is accepting the 400.5. pls help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Should it not accept *any* decimals, or just decimals in the 100 to 400 range?

Comment: it can accept. it can accept 101.1 but it should not accept 400.99. since 400.99 is greater than 400. it should not accept greater than 400

Comment: itcan accept decimals within 100 to 400 range

Comment: Why are you using the intValue message when want to compare floats or doubles? Doesn't floatValue or doubleValue make more sense?

Comment: would it not be easier to convert the content of `UITextField` to `double` and make comparison between `double` and `double`...? quick idea: `if ([myTextfield.text doubleValue] <= 400.f && [myTextField.text doubleValue] >= 100.f) { ...in range... } else { ...outside of range... }`. it makes more sense for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `NSString` returned by your text field to an `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *textFieldNumber = [formatter numberFromString:[textField text]];
```

Then use

```
[textFieldNumber decimalValue] > 100.0 && [textFieldNumber decimalValue] < 400
```

to check the range.

Comment: I used this . but i get an error as invalid operands to binary exp. its not accepting nsnumber for comparison.  if (([textFieldNumber decimalValue] < [MinNumber decimalValue]) || ([textFieldNumber decimalValue] > [MaxNumber decimalValue]) ) {

Comment: see my post in thesame question. I have posted the updated code

Comment: And you get "invalid operands" when you use that?

Answer (score 0):

i have converted the (textfield.text)string to double value and i compare double to double value. It works Fine. thanks for all your answers.